# How to show data in model coresponding to another model data

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

How to make a custom filter in angularjs for filtering data based on 1 criteria nad displaying the corresponding data in another model.??? in dis code, i want to show subject name corresponding to the fee, if i enter 165 in fee then subject Name model shoud show math.

```html
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Angular JS Filters</title>
   </head>
   <body>
     <h2>AngularJS Sample Application</h2>
     <div ng-app="" ng-controller="studentController">

        <table border="0">
            <tr><td>Enter first name:</td><td><input type="text" ng-model="student.firstName"></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Enter last name: </td><td><input type="text" ng-model="student.lastName"></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Enter fees: </td><td><input type="text" ng-model="subjectFee"></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Enter subject: </td><td><input type="text" ng-model="subjectName"></td></tr>
       </table>
       <br/>

       <table border="0">
       <tr><td>Name in Upper Case: </td><td>{{student.fullName() | uppercase}}</td></tr>
       <tr><td>Name in Lower Case: </td><td>{{student.fullName() | lowercase}}</td></tr>

       <tr><td>Fee:</td><td>
          <ul>

             <li ng-repeat="subject in student.subjects | filter: subjectFee |orderBy:'marks'">
                 {{  ' fee:' + subject.fee }}
            </li>
         </ul>
      </td></tr>

      <tr><td>Subject:</td><td>
       <ul>

           <li ng-repeat="subject in student.subjects | filter: subjectName |orderBy:'marks'">
               {{ subject.name + ', marks:' + subject.marks +', fee:' + subject.fee  }}
         </li>
      </ul>
     </td></tr>
    </table>
   </div>

  </script>

  <script>
    function studentController($scope) {
       $scope.student = {
       firstName: "Mahesh",
       lastName: "Parashar",
       subjects:[
            {name:'Physics',marks:70, fee:170},
            {name:'Chemistry',marks:80, fee:180},
            {name:'Math',marks:65, fee:165}
       ],
       fullName: function() {
            var studentObject;
            studentObject = $scope.student;
            return studentObject.firstName + " " + studentObject.lastName;
       }
    };
  }
  </script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js">  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following change in your code can generate the desired output.

```
<li ng-repeat="subject in student.subjects | filter: (subjectFee || subjectName) |orderBy:'marks'">
```

Comment: its good but the subject name should be shown in "enter subject" modal also automatically on entering 165.

Comment: i would prefer an answer containing a custom filter which does the same job along with showing the values in modal.